# How can I redefine bold to mean "semi-bold"?

Tags: fonts, bold

I'm using a type family that supports a semi-bold (`sb`) face, and I'd like to use that whenever `\textbf` is called for. How can I redefine `\textbf` to do this? Can I do it on a per family basis, or only for all families in my document at once?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Fonts are identified by five attributes:

1. encoding
2. family
3. series (weight)
4. shape
5. size

For the first four attributes, LaTeX maintains "default" definitions, contained in

1. `\encodingdefault`
2. `\familydefault`
3. `\seriesdefault`
4. `\shapedefault`

but also other commands

- Family defaults: `\rmdefault`, `\sfdefault`, `\ttdefault`
- Series defaults: `\mddefault`, `\bfdefault`
- Shape defaults: `\updefault`, `\itdefault`, `\sldefault`, `\scdefault`

When you call `\bfseries` (or `\textbf`, which calls `\bfseries` internally), LaTeX looks at `\bfdefault`, whose normal definition is

```
\newcommand{\bfdefault}{bx}
```

and doesn't change any of the other attributes.

At a lower level LaTeX maintains also

1. `\f@encoding`
2. `\f@family`
3. `\f@series`
4. `\f@shape`
5. `\f@size` and `\f@baselineskip`

Your problem seems to be in the fact that the sans serif family has a "semibold" shape that you want to be selected in case `\bfseries` is called, but the roman and typewriter families don't.

A definition such as

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{\ifx\f@family\sfdefault sb\else bx\fi}
\makeatother
```

will do the right thing unless you call a family changing command after the switch for bold face. So

```
\textrm{\textbf{x}}
```

would work, while `\textbf{\textrm{x}}` wouldn't.

Another way is to use `\DeclareFontShape` as explained by David Carlisle

```
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{sb}
\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{sb}{n}
    {<->ssub*\rmdefault/bx/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{sb}{sl}
    {<->ssub*\rmdefault/bx/sl}{}
```

and similarly for the typewriter type family.

In case you're using `fontspec` the situation is completely different, as you can fix the boldface variant on a family basis, as explained by rdhs.

Comment: I set my sans family (which is the one I'm trying to change) with `\usepackage[defaultsans]{open sans}` and both methods above behave as if they don't recognize `\sfdefault`. The first method does nothing, while the second fails with "Font family `T1+fos' unknown".

Comment: I've modified the examples to reflect the new info

Comment: Thanks, the `\DeclareFontShape` method now works; the `\ifx\f@family\sfdefault` has no effect.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It doesn't because `opensans` doesn't act as expected.

Comment: @egreg for applying this change globally, I imagine `\renewcommand\bfdefault{sb}` would do the trick — would you then have any idea why https://pastebin.com/W7q2LNdn doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @egreg would you be able to help?

Answer (score 15):

If you're already using `fontspec`, just adjust the `BoldFont` setting for each family:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[BoldFont="Minion Pro Semibold"]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[BoldFont="Myriad Pro Semibold"]{Myriad Pro}
```

Comment: I had to omit the quotes to get it working, but apart from this it is a nice solution.

Answer (score 7):

Globally you can override the default definition of

```
 \newcommand\bfdefault{bx}
```

with

```
\renewcommand\bfdefault{sb}
```

To do it for a single face, probably the easiest is to have a command like this one (from the base ot1cmtt.fd file)

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}
  {<->ssub*cmtt/m/n}{}
```

which substitutes non bold tt font for the bold version, just adjust the arguments for the font family you want to change.

Comment: could you please explain the arguments here? (like, what is "n"? is it an integer parameter?)