# Declare a new font shape

Tags: fonts

In my document `\bfseries` is defined to select the "semibold" shape, however the typewriter family (beramono) does not have a "semibold" shape. So I receive a warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/fvm/sb/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/fvm/m/n' instead on input line 250.
```

I tried the solution discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47883/how-can-i-redefine-bold-to-mean-semi-bold) by using the follwoing command to declare a new font shape for typewriter family.

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fvm}{sb}{n}{<->ssub*fvm/b/n}{}
```

or

```
\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{sb}{n}{<->ssub*\ttdefault/b/n}{}
```

And for both commands I received the follwoing error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Font family `T1+fvm' unknown.
```

A working example is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[oldstyle,semibold,type1]{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}% typewriter font 

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fvm}{sb}{n}{<->ssub * fvm/b/n}{}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily\bfseries Hello World!

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to issue an appropriate `\DeclareFontFamily` command before any `\DeclareFontShape` related to it.

Comment: @egreg, the font familiy is available in the documnet. I thought it should be declared by the package `beramono`. If I go to declare the font family, I should also declare the _bold_ shape and maybe different sizes fot it. Is there an easy way to copy _bold_ shape as _semi-bold_?

Comment: The `\DeclareFontFamily` command is in the `.fd` file that's not read until some text has to be typeset with a font from that family. Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @Aydin You can just load the `.fd` file with `\input` before issuing your `\DeclareFontShape`.

Comment: @StephanLehmke, thanks alot, adding .fd solved the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LaTeX needs to see a `\DeclareFontFamily` declaration before a `\DeclareFontShape` command can be issued.

A simple way out is to add

```
\sbox0{\ttfamily X}
```

after `\usepackage[<options>]{beramono}`, which will cause the corresponding `.fd` file to be read in, which contains the appropriate `\DeclareFontFamily` command.

Comment: It is not necessary to use a box. A simple `\ttfamily` or (if you fear side effects) a local `{\ttfamily}` is enough to trigger the loading of the fd-file.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to egreg and Stephan, loading the `.fd` file before `\DeclareFontShape` solved the problem.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[oldstyle,semibold,type1]{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}% typewriter font 

\makeatletter
\input{t1fvm.fd}
\makeatother

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{fvm}{sb}{n}{<->ssub * fvm/b/n}{}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily\bfseries Hello World!

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can force the loading also with `\sbox0{\ttfamily X}`

Comment: @egreg, thanks. I will do so, as it's more general.