# Roboto light condensed undefined font shape warning

Tags: fonts, warnings

I'm using the Roboto light condensed font, and always get the following font warning:

> Font shape `OT1/cmr/lc/n' undefined(Font) using` OT1/cmr/m/n' instead

An example document to generate the warning would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault, light, condensed]{roboto}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    Why does Roboto font give a warning?
\end{document}
```

I am using pdflatex through TeXLive.
Anyone any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

With PDFLaTeX package `roboto` loads `fontenc` after changing some defaults but before changing the default family. So, while loading `fontenc` still `cmr` is the valid family. The package is one of the exceptions that are actually reloaded on every `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage`. So the line

```
\usefont\encodingdefault\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault
```

in the file is executed, even if you'd load the package yourself before `roboto`. And at this time `\familydefault` is still `cmr`. This results in a (in your case not needed) selection of a light condensed version of `cmr`, that does not exist.

You can simply ignore the warning. If you really, really have to avoid the warning, you can disable loading package `fontenc` inside `roboto` (and optionally load is yourself before the package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontenc}
% NOTE: I DO NOT RECOMMEND TO DO THIS, BUT IT MAKES THE FONT WARNING GO AWAY.
\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{fontenc}
\makeatother
\usepackage[sfdefault, light, condensed]{roboto}
\makeatletter
\reenable@package@load{fontenc}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Roboto font does not give a warning. Produces light condensed text.
\end{document}
```

But of course this is at your own risk!

Comment: Thnx. Found also another solution: `\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{lc}{n}{<->ssub*cmr/m/n}{}`, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47883/how-can-i-redefine-bold-to-mean-semi-bold). It defines the font shape that is missing to prevent any warning.

Comment: @dikdirk Yes, if you also don't want a warning, if someone really tries to use a light condensed version of CMR, this would also be a solution. You can extend it to one more answer and even accept it, if you prefer this one.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Compile using lualatex.
\usepackage[sfdefault, light, condensed]{roboto}
\begin{document}
    Roboto font does not give a warning. Produces light condensed text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found also this workaround:

```
\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{cmr}{lc}{n}{<->ssub*cmr/m/n}{}
\usepackage[sfdefault, light, condensed]{roboto}
```

It sets the missing font (light condensed) for the default LaTeX computer modern font (cmr) to normal cmr.

As Roboto probably should not load cmr light condensed in the first place, it doesn't solve the root problem. But it prevents the warning in a safe way.