Intermediate boldness in tables
The following code produces the table below. Is it possible to produce the same table, but with a level of boldness intermediate between regular and classic bold. The lines of the table should be thicker.
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Field:&\multicolumn{1}{c@{\hspace{1pt}}|}{*}&Name&Type\\%
\hline
Table: & Tab & Tab & Tab \\
\hline
Sort:&Ascending&&\\%
\hline
Show:&\multicolumn{1}{c@{\hspace{1pt}}|}{X}&&\\%
\hline
Criteria:&&Like ``Some'' & ``*Day*'' \\
\hline
Or: & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



cmr is only available in two weights even in T1 encoding there are other fonts available in more weights or you could use lualatex and an opentype font and adjust the weight arbitrarily either with "fake bold" fontspec adjustment or using a variable font (the same answer whether or not you have a table)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47883/how-can-i-redefine-bold-to-mean-semi-bold

Thanks, @DavidCarlisle, for your very helpful comments! Meanwhile, I have came across xfakebold. I am not sure whether it does the trick.

oh pdf render OK that's basically the same as the opentype fakebold I mentioned above, but for type1 pdftex fonts. it's not as good as a real designed fonts (it just thickens the lines of path of the existing font so some designs show more artifacts than others) but it's Ok if you don't push it too far.

Thanks again, @DavidCarlisle! I am going to give it a try. In truth, I do not need a too bold font, but only a bit bolder than the regular non-bold fonts.

Not sure what you're trying to achieve by writing \multicolumn{1}{c@{\hspace{1pt}}|}{*}. Why not write \multicolumn{1}{c|}{*}?

Are you trying to get intermediate table widths, or fonts with a semibold weight?

@Davislor: I am trying to get both.


The lines of the table should be thicker.

The width of the horizontal and vertical rules in a tabular environment is governed by the parameter \arrayrulewidth. In most LaTeX document classes I'm familiar width, the default value of \arrayrulewidth is 0.4pt. The following example shows how to double this value to 0.8pt, while keeping the overall width of the tabular environment unchanged. (This is achieved by reducing slightly the value of \tabcolsep, which governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace padding.)

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Field: & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{*} & Name & Type \\
\hline
Table: & Tab & Tab & Tab \\
\hline
Sort:  & Ascending & & \\
\hline
Show:  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X} & & \\
\hline
Criteria: & & Like ``Some'' & ``*Day*'' \\
\hline
Or: & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\smallskip

\addtolength\arrayrulewidth{0.4pt} % default: 0.4pt
% Keep table's overall width unchanged. Note: 5*0.4pt=2pt=8*0.25pt
\addtolength\tabcolsep{-0.25pt}    


\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Field: & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{*} & Name & Type \\
\hline
Table: & Tab & Tab & Tab \\
\hline
Sort:  & Ascending & & \\
\hline
Show:  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{X} & & \\
\hline
Criteria: & & Like ``Some'' & ``*Day*'' \\
\hline
Or: & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Thanks, @Mico, for your very helpful code.

@PaulS - You're welcome. Just out of idle curiosity: Did I guess right by surmising that your (current) main typesetting objective is to thicken the horizontal lines?

Thanks, @Mico. Thicker table lines and bolder fonts are my objective. The reason is that we have many tables to print in small size and we find that readability might be improved by thicken the table lines as well as making the fonts bolder.

I have meanwhile found a solution: Using package mlmodern, which corresponds to a bit thicker version of default LaTeX font.
